# WPF DevExpress TextEdit - " * " for Password input

Tags: wpf, textbox, devexpress

how I can use TextEdit component for passwords input?I want to se some "*" or "#" or another symbol when I type the password. Is there some property, where i can set such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the [PasswordBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.aspx) control...

Comment: I want to use DevExpress TextEdit control. If i put Password box,  I would have big problems with styles, becouse other controlls all are fro mdevexpress.

Comment: @Vytas999: You should *not* accept an answer that... well... is not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try: TextEdit.Properties.PasswordChar = '*'